# Remove lines from CSV created through send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail

I am running a send_dbmail in a procedure and creating a csv-file. But I would like to remove 2 things from the file:
[image]

I would like to remove line 2 and the last line(3 rows affected). Is there a way?

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

to remove 3 rows affected, use SET NOCOUNT ON at beginning of the query.
at end of the query, you should use SET NOCOUNT OFF.
I wan to know, why/How you are getting  line 2 there?

Where you are using and what type of result set exactly you required?

Comment: Sorry for late feedback.

It is like this:
@query = 'SELECT * FROM NSGstat.dbo.test'